# How to return to previous activity in android using Kotlin when you have null object?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have trouble to navigate back to previous activity because I have null object so this code doesn't work.

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    if (item.itemId == R.id.home) {
        finish()
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

item is not null object.

Any ideas????

Comment: You want to kill activity when item is null ??

Comment: share the error from logcat

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter

Comment: check if id home exist in menu file and you implemented menu correct way

Answer (score 1):

When you declare your parameter as non null (`MenuItem` instead `MenuItem?`), Kotlin compiler adds code to make sure the item is not null (and throw `NullPointerException` if needed).

Since this parameter can be null, you need to use `MenuItem?` and get the item id using `item?.itemId` instead `item.itemId`:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
    if (item?.itemId == R.id.home) {
        finish()
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```